# Parsing XML file with DomDocument::load(), attribute information is missing

Tags: php, xml

So I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product id="nokia-asha-305-bite-feed">
   <title>Nokia Asha 305</title>
   <description />
   <item_price>280</item_price>
   <stock>1</stock>
   <ean_code />
   <prex_code />
   <wholesaler />
   <wholesaler_code />
   <manufacturer>nokia</manufacturer>
   <manufacturer_code />
   <image_url>http://www.bite.lt/bin/common9/common/devices/Nokia-Asha_305.png?w=130&amp;h=275</image_url>
   <product_url>http://www.bite.lt/lt/privatiems/telefonai/nokia/asha305</product_url>
   <specs>
      <spec name="USB">microUSB 2.0</spec>
      <spec name="Sinchronizacija su kompiuteriu">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Dviejų SIM kortelių palaikymas">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Dažnis">900/1800 MHz</spec>
      <spec name="Ekrano raiška">240×400 taškų</spec>
      <spec name="Ekrano spalvos">65 tūkst. spalvų</spec>
      <spec name="Baterija">Li-Ion (BL-4U)</spec>
      <spec name="Budėjimo laikas iki (val.)">528</spec>
      <spec name="Naršyklė">HTML</spec>
      <spec name="EDGE">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="3G (HSDPA)">-</spec>
      <spec name="Muzikos grotuvas">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Fotokamera">2 Mpix

    (1600x1200)</spec>
      <spec name="Telefono atmintis (MB)">10 MB</spec>
      <spec name="Meniu lietuvių kalba">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Laisvų rankų funkcija">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Kalendorius">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Žinutės">SMS, MMS</spec>
      <spec name="Bluetooth">2.1 su EDR</spec>
      <spec name="3G dažnis">-</spec>
      <spec name="Svoris su baterija (g)">98</spec>
      <spec name="Ekrano dydis">3.0"</spec>
      <spec name="Baterijos talpa (mAh)">1110 mAh</spec>
      <spec name="GPRS">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="3G (UMTS)">-</spec>
      <spec name="Atminties kortelė">
         microSD
         <a href="javascript:;" class="__callTip" title="iki 32GB, 2GB pakuotėje">Daugiau</a>
      </spec>
      <spec name="Diktofonas">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Radijas (FM)">Yra


    (Stereo FM su RDS)</spec>
      <spec name="GPS">-</spec>
      <spec name="Elektroninis paštas telefone">Yra</spec>
      <spec name="Telefonų knygelės atmintis">1000</spec>
      <spec name="Operacinė sistema">Nokia OS S40</spec>
      <spec name="Papildoma informacija">
         Galimybė atsisiųsti 40 nemokamų "EA" žaidimų ("Tetris", "Bejeweled", "Need for Speed The Run", "Fifa 2012" ir kt.)
         <br />
         <br />
         Prieiga prie socialinių tinklų (Facebook, Twitter, Youtube ir kt.)
         <br />
         <br />
         Daugiau informacijos:
         <a href="http://www.nokia.com/lt-lt/produktai/telefonas/305/savybes/" target="a_blank">rasite čia.</a>
      </spec>
      <spec name="Jutiklinis">Yra</spec>
   </specs>
   <categories>
      <category>Telefonai</category>
   </categories>
</product>
```

How would I convert it to an associative array, without losing the attributes in 'specs' element.

At the moment I have this:

```
 $item_xml = simplexml_load_string($this->xml_parser->readOuterXML(), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

This works fine for the top most element. But for specs element I lose all the attribute info, and only get a flat array with the values of each `spec` element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look output. I think that all ok

```
foreach($item_xml->specs->spec as $spec) {
  foreach( $spec->attributes()  as $att )
    echo $att ."\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this function, it's old and I didn't code it but works very well. If you want the attributes too let `get_attributes` param to 1. In the comments you have a link if you want to know more.

```
/**
 * xml2array() will convert the given XML text to an array in the XML structure.
 * Link: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/
 * Arguments : $contents - The XML text
 *                $get_attributes - 1 or 0. If this is 1 the function will get the attributes as well as the tag values - this results in a different array structure in the return value.
 *                $priority - Can be 'tag' or 'attribute'. This will change the way the resulting array sturcture. For 'tag', the tags are given more importance.
 * Return: The parsed XML in an array form. Use print_r() to see the resulting array structure.
 * Examples: $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml'));
 *              $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml', 1, 'attribute'));
 */ 
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'attribute', $encode='UTF-8') {
    if(!$contents) return array();

    if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) {
        //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!";
        return array();
    }

    //Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work
    $parser = xml_parser_create('');
    if($encode!='')
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, $encode); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm...

    //Initializations
    $xml_array = array();
    $parents = array();
    $opened_tags = array();
    $arr = array();

    $current = &$xml_array; //Refference

    //Go through the tags.
    $repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array
    foreach($xml_values as $data) {
        unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble

        //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope
        // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array).
        extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler.

        $result = array();
        $attributes_data = array();

        if(isset($value)) {
            if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value;
            else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
        }

        //Set the attributes too.
        if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) {
            foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) {
                if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val;
                else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
            }
        }

        //See tag status and do the needed.
        if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>'
            $parent[$level-1] = &$current;
            if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;

                $current = &$current[$tag];

            } else { //There was another element with the same tag name

                if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;
                } else {//This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2;

                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                    }

                }
                $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1;
                $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index];
            }

        } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />'
            //See if the key is already taken.
            if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;


            } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array)
                if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array...

                    // ...push the new element into that array.
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;

                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) {
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;

                } else { //If it is not an array...
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) {
                        if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                            $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                            unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                        }

                        if($attributes_data) {
                            $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                        }
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken
                }
            }

        } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>'
            $current = &$parent[$level-1];
        }
    }

    return($xml_array);

}
```